# pass a wildcard as IN parameter to stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass a wildcard character as an IN parameter when calling a stored procedure (jsp with MySQL)

If I have (in my stored procedure)-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `duration`(IN varassetid varchar(25), IN vardtmin datetime, IN vardtmax datetime)
```

This works fine if calling with -

```
CALL duration(1157, '2015-06-29 11:47:28', '2015-07-02 11:47:28');
```

But not with -

```
CALL duration('%', '2015-06-29 11:47:28', '2015-07-02 11:47:28');
```

or with any other wildcard character combination. 
I do not want to have to change the stored procedure if possible.

Thoughts appreciated

Comment: What do you mean about `not with`?

Comment: If I use wildcard '%' or '%%%%' etc the call produces no records, I need to return all records (not just those with assetid=1157)

Comment: Was your condition operator  `LIKE` in `where` clause?

Comment: No, its a direct SELECT assetid

Comment: Without `LIKE`, I don't think you can fetch all records with `%`.

Comment: So it seems, sadly